# Firefox and Chromium from snaps unusable due to graphical glitches

Tags: graphics, firefox, snap, chromium, 23.04

After upgrading Ubuntu to 23.04, I can no longer use Firefox nor Chromium provided as snaps.

First, this is how Chromium looks like:

[glitchy Chromium ran from snap package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHFyg.jpg)

Firefox from snap behaves the same way. The problem is present in GNOME 44 both under Wayland and Xorg.

Firefox installed from [mozillateam's PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam) works absolutely without any issues. (I am typing this post from that version.)

Here's the output from running `glxinfo -B`:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: AMD (0x1002)
    Device: AMD Radeon RX 5500 XT (navi14, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.49, 6.2.0-1003-lowlatency) (0x7340)
    Version: 23.0.2
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 8192MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
Memory info (GL_ATI_meminfo):
    VBO free memory - total: 7509 MB, largest block: 7509 MB
    VBO free aux. memory - total: 7886 MB, largest block: 7886 MB
    Texture free memory - total: 7509 MB, largest block: 7509 MB
    Texture free aux. memory - total: 7886 MB, largest block: 7886 MB
    Renderbuffer free memory - total: 7509 MB, largest block: 7509 MB
    Renderbuffer free aux. memory - total: 7886 MB, largest block: 7886 MB
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 8192 MB
    Total available memory: 16183 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 7509 MB
OpenGL vendor string: AMD
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon RX 5500 XT (navi14, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.49, 6.2.0-1003-lowlatency)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.0.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 23.0.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

One additional detail that may or may not be relevant is that because my motherboard is old, it can't boot with the above card. For that reason, I also have an ancient nVidia Geforce 210 plugged in and blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. That ensures the machine starts, and after that the nvidia isn't used in any capacity.

I have no issues running any other applications, including games, both native and under Proton/WINE. No other snap application presents these glitches either (tested by running the newest version of Blender).

Any clues how to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Replying to myself, this is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/2004532